# Most "ruby-like" way of combining two controllers in Ramaze

Tags: ruby, ramaze

**How can I split up my codebase in Ramaze into different controller classes, and what is the most "ruby-like" way of doing so?**

I have a basic project in Ramaze that I want to split into multiple files. Right now, I am using one controller class for everything and adding on to it with open classes. Ideally, each distinct part of the controller would be in its own class, but I don't know how to do that in Ramaze.

I want be able to add more functionality, and more separate controller classes, without adding on too much boilerplate code. Here's what I'm doing right now:

init.rb

```
require './othercontroller.rb'

class MyController < Ramaze::Controller
  map '/'
  engine :Erubis

  def index
    @message = "hi"
  end
end
Ramaze.start :port => 8000
```

othercontroller.rb

```
class MyController < Ramaze::Controller
  def hello
    @message = "hello"
  end
end
```

Any suggestions on how to split up this logic would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do it is to require your controllers in `init.rb`, and define each class in it own file, and require it in init like so :

controller/init.rb :

```
# Load all other controllers
require __DIR__('my_controller')
require __DIR__('my_other_controller')
```

controller/my_controller.rb :

```
class MyController < Ramaze::Controller
  engine :Erubis

  def index
    @message = "hi"
  end

  # this will be fetched via /mycontroller/hello
  def hello
    @message = "hello from MyController"
  end
end
```

controller/my_other_controller.rb :

```
class MyOtherController < Ramaze::Controller
  engine :Erubis

  def index
    @message = "hi"
  end

  # this will be fetched via /myothercontroller/hello
  def hello
    @message = "hello from MyOtherController"
  end
end
```

You can create a base class you inherit from so you don't have to repeat `engine :Erubis` line (and probably others) in each class.

If you want to serve `MyController` at the '/' URI, you can map it to '/' :

```
class MyController < Ramaze::Controller
  # map to '/' so we can call '/hello'
  map '/'
  ...
```

You can peek at the blog example for an example: https://github.com/Ramaze/ramaze/tree/master/examples/app/blog